# FLASK: Creating table in JINJA from python dict

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to build a `table` in HTML from a dict.

I have the following data:

```
alternativas = { 'attribute1':[val1, val2, val3] , 'attribute2':[val4, val5]}
```

and I want to display a table like:

```
attribute1         attribute2
val1                val4
val2                val5
val3
```

I have tried with:

```
{% for dict_item in alternativas %}
        <tr>
           {% for value in alternativas.values() %}
                {% for item in value %}
                    <td> {{ item }} </td>
                {% endfor %}
           {% endfor %}
        </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

But I can't get the results I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You right code should be (amended line is commented):

```
{% for dict_item in alternativas %}
        <tr>
           {% for value in alternativas[dict_item] %} #amended line
                {% for item in value %}
                    <td> {{ item }} </td>
                {% endfor %}
           {% endfor %}
        </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

or more concisely:

```
{% for key, value in alternativas %}
            <tr>
               {% for item in value %}
                        <td> {{ item }} </td>
               {% endfor %}
            </tr>
     {% endfor %}
```

Not sure if it works properly though, as jinja looping through dictionaries is sometimes tricky